# Find $f'(2)$, where $f(x) =\frac{h(x)}{x}$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Consider the function $h(x)$, for which $h(2) = 4$ and $h'(2) =-3$. Find $f'(2)$ for the function $f(x) = \frac{h(x)}{x}$.

---

**Progress**: I know that $h(x)/x$ is equivalent to $h(x) x^{-1}$; should I use the product rule?

Comment: Do you have any thoughts? Are there any rules which describe differentiation of quotients?

Comment: I know that h(x)/x is equivalent to h(x)*x^-1, and I should maybe use the product rule?

Comment: Note that the product rule and the quotient rule are the same. You can use one to prove the other by using the definition of inverses like you wrote above, and applying the chain rule.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint*
By the quotient rule:
$$f'(x)=\frac{h'(x)\cdot x - (1)h(x)} {x^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Use the quotient rule, which states:
$$\left(\frac f g\right)' = \frac{f'g - g'f}{g^2}$$
Whereby:
\begin{align}
f'(x) &= \frac{h'(x)\cdot x - 1\cdot h(x)}{x^2}
\\
f'(2) &= \frac{h'(2)\cdot 2 - 1\cdot h(2)}{4}
\\
&= \frac{(-3)\cdot 2 - 1\cdot 4}{4}
\\
&= \frac{-10}{4}
\\
&= - \frac 5 2
\end{align}